# how to pass searchview text from action bar to another activity

Tags: android, json

i am passing text from searchveiw in action bar to another activity by intent

```
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        searchcity=query;
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"searchcity"+ searchcity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SearchActivity.class);

           intent.putExtra("SerachcityName", searchcity);
           startActivity(intent);



        return true;
    }
```

and retrieving in another activity as like this but text is not showing so please any one help me

```
searchcity=getIntent().getExtras().getString("SerachcityName");
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "searchcity"+searchcity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Comment: Your query is not empty???

Comment: Does `getIntent().hasExtras()` return true?

Comment: check whether you get the query correct, by adding a 
    Log.w("Search Queary", "Search:" + query);

just before 

intent.putExtra("SerachcityName", searchcity);

Comment: thanks to all of you i got my mistake

Comment: hello friends how can i pass this  query to fragment actually i have to show hotels on fragment based on search city which are having in query (above mentioned string query)

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually show the Toast

edit this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "searchcity"+searchcity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

as

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "searchcity"+searchcity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: if that helps, pls accept my answer bro :-)

@ParamatmaSharanUpadhyay

Comment: @ParamatmaSharanUpadhyay

Answer (score 0):

You only call :

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("SerachcityName"); //nothing is default value if have not passed value, you can set any value like null.
```